# 'ContentCreateUpdateView' object has no attribute 'module_id'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, mixins

I am following the tutorial on this book.

Everything was fine until I got to this view here.

The console return the issue below when i click on the page that has the link to the view below.
(FROM THE HTML BELOW, its the link MANAGE CONTENTS)

Full error traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/welearn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/welearn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 156, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/welearn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 154, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/welearn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 106, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/welearn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    content = template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/welearn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/welearn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/welearn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/welearn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/welearn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/welearn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/welearn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/welearn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/welearn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/welearn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/welearn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/welearn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/welearn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 512, in render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/welearn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/welearn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/welearn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 209, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/welearn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/welearn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 442, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/welearn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 90, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/macadmin/Documents/Django_wapps/welearn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 622, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'module_content_list' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['module/(?P<module_id>[0-9]+)/$']
```

views.py

```
class ContentCreateUpdateView(TemplateResponseMixin, View):
    """
    Create and update contents from different models.
    """
    module = None
    model = None
    obj = None
    template_name = 'core/manage/content/form.html'

    def get_model(self, model_name):
        if model_name in ['text', 'video', 'image', 'file']:
            # app label == app installed
            return apps.get_model(app_label='core', model_name=model_name)

        return None

    def get_form(self, model, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Build dynamic form. 
        Check that the given model name is one of the four content models.
        """
        Form = modelform_factory(model, exclude=['owner', 'order', 'created', 'updated'])
        return Form(*args, **kwargs)

    def dispatch(self, request, module_id, model_name, id=None):
        self.module = get_object_or_404(Module, id=module_id, course__owner=request.user)
        self.model = self.get_model(model_name)
        if id:
            self.obj = get_object_or_404(self.model, id=id, owner=request.user)

        return super(ContentCreateUpdateView, self).dispatch(request, module_id, model_name, id)


    def get(self, request, module_id, model_name, id=None):
        form = self.get_form(self.model, instance=self.obj)
        return self.render_to_response({'form':form, 'object':self.obj})


    def post(self, request, module_id, model_name, id=None):
        form = self.get_form(self.model, instance=self.obj, data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.owner = request.user
            obj.save()
            if not id:
                # new content
                Content.objects.create(module=self.module, item=obj)

            return redirect('core:module_content_list', self.module_id)
        return self.render_to_response({'form':form, 'object':self.obj})
```

list.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}My Courses{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>My courses</h1>
<div class="module">
    {% for course in object_list %}
        <div class="course-info mt-5 ml-3">
            <h3>{{ course.title }}</h3>
            <p>
                <a href="{% url 'core:course_edit' course.id %}">Edit</a>
                <a href="{% url 'core:course_delete' course.id %}">Delete</a>
                <a href="{% url 'core:course_module_update' course.id %}">Edit modules</a>
                {% if course.modules.count > 0%}
                    <a href="{% url 'core:module_content_list' course.modules.first.id %}">Manage contents</a>
                {% endif %}
            </p>
        </div>
    {% empty %}
        <p>You haven't created any courses yet.</p>
    {% endfor %} 
    <p>
        <a href="{% url 'core:course_create' %}" class="button">Create new course</a>
    </p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ManagerCourseListView.as_view(), name='manage_course_list'),
    path('create/', views.CourseCreateView.as_view(), name='course_create'),
    path('<pk>/edit/', views.CourseUpdateView.as_view(), name='course_edit'),
    path('<pk>/delete/', views.CourseDeleteView.as_view(), name='course_delete'),
    path('<pk>/module/', CourseModuleUpdateView.as_view(), name='course_module_update'),
    path('module/<int:module_id>/content/<model_name>/create/', views.ContentCreateUpdateView.as_view(),
        name='module_content_create'),
    path('module/<int:module_id>/content/<model_name>/<id>/', views.ContentCreateUpdateView.as_view(),
        name='module_content_update'),
    path('content/<int:id>/delete/', views.ContentDeleteView.as_view(), name='module_content_delete'),
    path('module/<int:module_id>/', views.ModuleContentListView.as_view(), name='module_content_list'),
]
```

If anyone has gone through this before please give me a hand.

I am currently using django 2.1 and python 3.7

Thank you

Comment: where is the path for module_content_list name?

Comment: @givejob i just updated the entire urls.py with path requested above.please let me know if you are able to solve it.

Comment: is course.modules.first.id contains value or None?

Comment: currently it is None, i just updated the line you just mentioned from the list.html above with a ```{% if course.modules.count > 0%}``` still nothing

Comment: @alasdair do you have any suggestion?